# Set associative cache with 48 bit adress

Tags: caching, operating-system, cpu-architecture

This question is from an exame my school made a year ago.

I have a N-way set associative cache with `48 bit adresses` and the `tag 33 bits`.

The cache can store `16384 double-type elements`, if the adress is multiple of 64.

The question is: How many sets and lines per set exist?

Since the capacity is 16384 double-type and a double has 8 byte, I put the `capacity in 16384 * 8 = 131072 byte`

I think the 48 bit (6 byte) adress is the dimension of a line.

I saw on a website that the Cache capacity / number of bits in a line = lines number so I put 131072 / 6 = 21845 (approximate).

I can't get further than this, since I don't find the way to get the sets and if I'm right with the number of lines per set, as this is my problem.

Thanks

Comment: This is really a hardware question.

Comment: The "if the address is multiple of 64." part seems to be telling you that the line size is 64 bytes.  If an array wasn't aligned to a cache-line boundary, it would take an extra cache line at the end.  So that gives you the number of bits for offset within a line, and 48 = tag + index + offset.